# How to pass parameters of a function using Context API + Hooks in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm using function component together with context api and hooks, I would like to know how to pass values ​​to be accessed by useContext by passing a function

```
 interface User{
   user: string;
   pass: string:
 }
 export const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  async function signIn(user : string, pass: string){
    const response = await auth.signIn() ;
    setUser(response.user);

  }

  return(
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{signIn}}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

the error is in 'value={{signIn}}'

```
    Type '(user: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<void>'.ts(2322) 
auth.tsx(18, 5): The expected type comes from property 'signIn' which is declared here on type 'AuthContextData'
```

I'm using inside a component:

```
const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
    const {signIn} = useContext(Context);
    const [userIn, setUser] = useState('');
    const [passIn, setPass] = useState('');

    async function handleSignIn(){
        await signIn(userIn, passIn);
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>            
            <TextInput onChangeText={text => setUser(text)} placeholder='User'></TextInput>
            <TextInput onChangeText={text => setPass(text)} secureTextEntry={true} placeholder='Password'></TextInput>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleSignIn}>
                <Text style={styles.textButton}>Sign In</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )

}
export default SignIn;
```

Comment: you are passing a function that requires two parameters and you don't pass anything

Comment: yes, but how do I pass these values ​​in the provider

Comment: Where/how are you using `signIn`?

Comment: I'm calling inside a component @go_diego

Comment: So just `signIn()`?

Comment: no, i'm passing the values. I edited the post @go_diego

Comment: How have you created AuthContext, could you please show that along with its typings

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, it was just changing the interface used by AuthContext

```
interface AuthContextData {
    user: User | null;
    loading: boolean;
    signIn(user: string, pass: string): Promise<void>;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextData>({} as AuthContextData)
```